# Excessive power consumption in suspend mode Dell xps 13 9365

Tags: battery, hibernate, xps

Using Ubuntu 18.10 on a newly purchased Dell xps 13 9365 (i7 model), everything seems to be working well except for suspend. Closing the laptop lid appears to put it in suspend mode, but the power consumption in this mode makes it a non-viable option if you leave it for more than a few hours. This is because it is using 5-10% of the battery charge per hour! Hibernation doesn't appear to be an option on this laptop; when I try to hibernate using terminal commands, it doesn't wake up. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Update: Using the powertop utility and optimizing power usage with it, I have reduced the battery drain in sleep to about 2.5% per hour. That is still far too high to allow one to put the laptop to sleep for a day, but it is progress.